# Pandas Concat method

Tags: python-3.x

I am using these two pandas DataFrames :

1. `t1 = pd.DataFrame(data=[['A',1], ['B', 2]])`
2. `t2 = pd.DataFrame(data=[['A',1], ['B', 2]])`

Please explain how the parameter join with **inner** and **outer** will work on the concatenated dataframe

Answer (score 0):

In this case both inner and outer give you the same result.

As the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#set-logic-on-the-other-axes) explains, join='outer' will concatenate and also return rows where the frames are not overlapping perfectly in terms of indices on the axis which you are not concatenating on and fill missing values with NaNs.

join='inner' will only return the rows where perfect overlap on the axis along which you are not concatenating is achieved.

```
t1 = pd.DataFrame(data={'letter':['A','B'], 'number':[1, 2]}, index=[1,2])
t2 = pd.DataFrame(data={'letter':['B','C'], 'number':[1, 2]}, index=[2,3])
pd.concat([t1,t2], join='outer', axis=1)
```

gives

```
    letter  number  letter  number
1   A   1.0 NaN NaN
2   B   2.0 B   1.0
3   NaN NaN C   2.0
```

`pd.concat([t1,t2], join='inner', axis=1)`

gives

```
    letter  number  letter  number
2   B   2   B   1
```

Comment: Thank you so much Sebastian.

Comment: If this is what you were looking for, can you accept the answer, please?